# Why do we use *that* instead of *those* in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, pronouns

Given this sentence:

> I wish I had shoes like that

Is it possible to say:

> I wish I had shoes like those

or not?

Why is the first correct?

Comment: Aslan, "that" is more common there, probably because of the elliptical form of "*a pair of* shoes".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both *shoes like that* and *shoes like those* are acceptable, because the referent may not be the shoes themselves but some (singular) property which they possess. For instance, you may admire a particular colour; or an ingenious fastening device; or a peculiarity of design suited to a particular activity.

> HE: I got these football shoes, you don't change the individual cleats, you snap a whole set on and off, like this (*demonstrates*) ...
>   YOU: Wow, I wish I had shoes like that.

So *like that* has such a broad range of possible referents that nobody really stops to worry about whether the referent in a particular instance is properly singular or plural.